# Embedding a web application in a mobile app?

Tags: python, android, ios, mobile

I have a flask app which works on local ip and i wonder if i can make a mobile app without writing the whole app in another language.I just wanna access the website on my phone with an application.Is there a way to do that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hello and welcome to the forum,

If I understand correctly, your application allows access to a website, which has a local IP address as URL.
You then want to develop an application to access it.

If what I just said is correct, then you don't need to develop an application at all. In fact, all you have to do is type in your phone's browser (in the search bar at the top) :
http://ton-ip-local:ton-port-local.

Hopefully this helps :)

Comment: Actually i wanted to access web app from a mobile application and not browser and i found out that there's some tools that views websites in applications in android and that helps me for now but Thanks anyway :)